# How to use a super(variable) instantiated in constructor?

Tags: java, super

Hello people of stackoverflow,

I am not completely sure if my question is redundant or not. However after instantiating a **variable** using **super()** in a **constructor**, how would you use the **super(variable)** in another method of the same class. I read somewhere that if you use "**protected**" in the parent class you should be able access it, however I wish to avoid doing so.

Example:

```
public class test extends trial{
    public test (trial variable){
        super(variable);
    }

    public double testMethod(){
    return [super(variable)]; //This is where the super(variable) is going
    }
}
```

Comment: `super(variable);` just call the parent constructor, there is nothing as "instantiating a variable using super()". If you want to access the parent's attributes in the child class, they must be defined as protected (or public).

Comment: Or just use a public/protected `getter` in the parent `trial` class.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish here? If you want a new `test`, you should say `return new test(variable)`. If you want an instance of `trial` instead, use `return new trial(variable)`.

Comment: @Idos Well not this particular example because I'm not using any real typed code, but in another setting it does when I am not using the super(variable).

Comment: @Holt I see, I was seeing if there was another way to access the parent attributes. Thanks

Comment: @resueman I am not trying to create a new test or trial. I am trying to use the existing variable.

Comment: @JavaSam As specified by DavidYee you could also use public or protected getters.

Comment: @Holt I see, I will go ahead and try it out.

Comment: @DavidYee I completely forgot about using protected getter. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I take it `Trail` looks somewhat like:

```
public class Trial {
   private final Trial variable;
   public Trail(Trial variable) {
      this.variable = variable;
   }
}
```

If that is the case then `Test` cannot access `super.variable` without changing the [access control](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html) of `variable` to protected (or higher) or having a protected (or higher) getter for `variable`. There is no other way round this (1).

> after instantiating a variable using super() in a constructor

You are not (directly) instantiating the variable, you are calling the constructor on `Trial`. Then the constructor in `Trial` is instantiating the variable.

1) You can get round this with evil hackory. However doing so would be a mistake in 99% of cases.

Comment: That makes a lot more sense to me now. Like i said in response to Mathew Hughes, I had figured it could be something similar but was only 30% sure.

Answer (score 0):

what you are doing is not initializing a variable instead you are calling parents constructor, i.e. trial's constructor.
super variable can be accessed from child class directly if they are protected or public.
for example

```
public class A{
public int foo;
protected int foo2;
private int foo3;
}

public class B extends A{
public void someMethod()
{
foo=1;
foo2=3;
//foo3 cant be accessed because it is private. only and only class A can
//access it.

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your superclass does not expose the thing you're receiving as a constructor argument and passing in to the superclass constructor, you can always have the subclass make its own reference to it:

```
public class Test extends Trial {
    private Trial variable;
    public Test(Trial variable) {
        super(variable);
        this.variable = variable;
    }

    public void testMethod() {
        this.variable.doWhatever();
    }
}
```

Comment: Your and mlk's explanation helps a lot. I figured it was something similar to what you two said but I was only 30% sure. If I could choose two answers, it would be both of you because you show directly a possible way but mlk is very detailed which helps me a lot.